# How do I search for a file based on what is output by a command running on that file

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I am working on a project for one of my professors and he asked me to sort a couple hundred .fits images based on their header files (specifically what star they are images of) I think that grep would be the best way to do this however I can't seam to figure out how to use grep based on the header.

I am entering:

```
ls | imhead *.fits | grep -E -r "PG\ 1104+243" *
```

to just list them out for now, once they are listed I know how to copy them into a directory.

I am new to using grep so I am unsure as to where my error lies? any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Something like `find . -name \*.fits -exec bash -c 'echo {}; imhead {} | grep -E "PG" {}' \;`

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do with that command line? `ls` lists files. Fine. Now what does `imhead` do? What does it do with an input stream that's a list of files (the `ls` output) and an argument list that's also a list of files (`*.fits`)? What are you trying to do with the `grep` afterwards? It seems like you want to use it to search recursively for files but also search for an ERE in the output from `imhead` and in the files it finds? What does `sort a couple hundred .fits images based on their header files` mean? What header files?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `imghead` will extract the headers of the `.fits` as txt, you can use a simple shell script to do it:

*script.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
grep "$1" "$2" > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "$2"
```

Note that the `+` is a special character if you use extended regular expression, meaning if you pass the `-E` as in the question. A simple grep without any options should do the trick here.

---

Use `find` to exec the script on every `*.fits` file in the current folder:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name '*.fits' -exec ./script.sh 'PG 1104+243' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to copy/move/alter or do something with the files you find, you might be better off, in terms of complexity and ease of quoting, using a loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -name \*.fits -print0 | while read -d '' -r file; do
    echo Checking file: $file
    imhead "$file" | grep -q 'PG 1104+243'
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
       echo Object matches: $file
    fi
done
```